# How to wait for a backup to finish before calling other code

Tags: java, oracle

I have a bash script that calls java code to create an oracle data pump backup. I want to add additional code to do something with the backup after it finishes, I am wondering if there is a way for the data pump to notify me of its completion or in general how to go about waiting for a long task to finish(hopefully without threads).

Comment: what have you tried? Are you familiar with Threading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monitor datapump jobs either using Datapump client or querying database catalog views.

As you are executing scripts, querying database catalog views will be your preferred choice.

The following queries can be used for this:

```
select owner_name,job_name,state from dba_datapump_jobs;


select b.username, 
       a.sid, 
       b.opname, 
       b.target,
       round(b.SOFAR*100/b.TOTALWORK,0) || '%' as "%DONE", 
       b.TIME_REMAINING,
       to_char(b.start_time,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') start_time
 from 
       v$session_longops b, 
       v$session a
where 
       a.sid = b.sid      
order by 6;
```

The idea would be to code a loop and query for datapump job termination inside this loop.

```
sql #1 : Query the status of the job.
sql #2 : Query the percentage of work done.
```